# rust serialport-rs reading blocked

Tags: windows, rust, serial-port

I am trying to use COM RS232 `serialport-rs` example `receive_data` and it only works on Mac or and Linux. It does not work on Windows 10. The example is blocked waiting for data and not receiving anything.

If I open the COM port with Arduino's serial monitor I see data coming into the PC's port, but Rust's serialport-rs example does not seems to receive anything. Anybody else have the same issue?

Library sources for reference https://gitlab.com/susurrus/serialport-rs

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
port.write_data_terminal_ready(true);
```

after opening the port.

I had the same thing happen, but it worked on the first run following running a different program (putty) when using the same serial port. The answer was here:
[Why can I not recieve serial data using Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502435/why-can-i-not-recieve-serial-data-using-rust)

Answer (score 1):

I know you might've found your issue but figures I'll post it anyway. You might need to change your flow control. I encountered this exact issue and I had to change my flow control to hardware control.

```
let mut final_port = serialport::new(&port_str, 115_200)
.timeout(Duration::from_millis(1000))
.open().expect("Failed to open port"); 
final_port.set_flow_control(serialport::FlowControl::Hardware).unwrap();
```