# Rust serial port read always empty/timeout

Tags: rust, serial-port

I'm trying to run a very basic rust program which opens the serial port and dumps to console all the data. However for some reason it always times out, i.e. nothing is received.

I'm confident that the serial port is working correctly since if i use serial tools i see the data comming in. i also tried to do it in python, and it works there.

Here is my code:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {

    let port_name = "COM8";
    let baud_rate = 9600;

    let port = serialport::new(port_name, baud_rate)
        .timeout(Duration::from_millis(100))
        .open();
    match port {
        Ok(mut port) => {
            let mut serial_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 1000];
            println!("Receiving data on {} at {} baud:", &port_name, &baud_rate);
            loop {
                match port.read(&mut serial_buf) {
                    Ok(t) => io::stdout().write_all(&serial_buf[..t]).unwrap(),
                    Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::TimedOut => (),
                    Err(e) => eprintln!("{:?}", e),
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to open \"{}\". Error: {}", port_name, e);
            ::std::process::exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. it just times out.

Comment: So the error you are getting is `io::ErorKind::TimedOut`? What if you remove the `timeout(Duration::from_millis(100))`, what happens then? Does it get stuck in `read`?

Comment: Also general remark: Use `exit(1)` as little as possible, because it doesn't run destructors of existing objects. This is a difference to python, where an exit internally throws an exception which closes scopes and runs cleanup procedures. Rust doesn't do that, `exit(1)` directly just kills the process. The preferred alternative would be to `panic!()` instead. Panics **do** run cleanup procedures. At the same time this would simplify your code, because you can `.expect(format!("Failed to open \"{}\".", port_name))` instead, which has the exact same effect as what you wrote, just with a panic.

Comment: If i remove the timeout, it stays stuck in read indefinitely, yes.

And noted for the exit(1), thanks for the tips.

I have to admit i'm totally stumped here. In python, using the default serial library it works just fine. As well as on MobaXTerm. But rust, nothing.

Comment: Since you haven't set parity, stop bits, flow control etc they are all assuming default values, maybe those defaults do not align with whatever is connected?

Comment: The device is a virtual com port, so those settings should have no effect. And i do the same in python.

Comment: For anyone else stuck, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502435/why-can-i-not-recieve-serial-data-using-rust